# centering titleView in navigationItem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem, cgrect, titleview

I am trying to center my titleView in my `navigationItem`.
After localizing my app, I saw this behavior:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

This is my code as an `extension` to `navigationItem`:

```
extension UINavigationItem{
func makeImg(){


    let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 200,height: 40))
    let logo = UIImage(named: "Rookie")
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 66.75, y: 7.25, width: 66.5, height: 25.5))
    imageView.image = logo
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true


    container.addSubview(imageView)
    self.titleView = container


}

}
```

I think it has something to do with my superView in navigationItem.
So I should reference the Screens bounds. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you wrap the imageView in container? You can set the imageView as titleView directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if the view set as `titleView` is very wide. Views that are added as a `titleView` are only resized if their width is wider than the available space, in which case they're resized to fill the space between the left bar button item and the right.

In this case, you've set your `container` object as being 200 points wide, which is wider than the available space with both of those items.

If you set the `container` width to match the image view (i.e., 66.5 points), then it should become centered. :)

(Or conversely, if you don't plan to add any other views, you can set the image view directly as the `titleView`)

Comment: tried to make it directly. worked like a charm. Thanks alot

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help! :)